# Favicons not showing up properly

Tags: html, css, favicon

I have a favicon.ico located in my root. I have linked like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Some people in my office can see it any some people can't. When I rename the file and the link path I get 100% success. When I change it back to favicon.ico some people see it and some people don't. It is totally unpredictable.

Is there anything unique to favicon's that would make this not work correctly?

Comment: Have that people that have problem tried to clear the cache?

Comment: does it have something to do with your path and the users "depth" in your site? for example `/blah` works but `/blah/blah` does not?

Comment: @DixonD, cache has been cleared and computers have been restarted!

Comment: @hunter, I questioned that in one of the below comments. I left the path at /favicon.ico so that the got the root path to the favicon from any level of the site. I tried leaving it at favicon.ico and was unable to see it on some pages.

Comment: are you using any programming language? You might need to resolve the root url to define the path to your favicon.ico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking [how to force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)?

Comment: That would work, but, some users can't even find the location of the favicon! The text of the image source comes up but the favicon can't be displayed. Pretty strange.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, I can't find the location. It has been 6 years, internet, haven't you learned??

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you need both of this definitions.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Work?

Comment: Well, if you hit http://example.com/test, the favicon won't show up because it is not located in the test directory...Right?

Comment: @Dan: Yeah, the location you specify would have to change depending on the file that it was specified in. If you have nested levels of pages, and you're not doing this, that could very well be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem with the default site.
I instead had problems with links on the same site.
The favicon did not show up on links

When I tried to access the favicon in the browser developer it showed 
permission denied.

I changed the permissions on the server and it worked on links.