# Firefox doesn't show favicon

Tags: html, favicon

I created favicon.ico file and declared it in my HTML head tag:

```
<link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" />
<link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
```

IE 8 and Opera handle it great but FireFox does not even try to load it (as I see from my Fiddler debug proxy). I've tried many different type (image/ico etc.) and href params but no luck.

What did I miss?

Comment: is your file really called `favicon.con` ?

Comment: Where is the favicon.ico file in relation to the html file?

Comment: @Jrod if it works with other browsers, the location should be fine

Comment: @Teneff Oh, I'm sorry... favicon.ico of course, just typo. Edited.

Comment: @MisterSir,  Not necessarily.  Some browsers may just try to load a file named favicon.ico from the root, and completely ignore the <link> tag.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like most things in the browser, favicons (or lack thereof) are common candidates for **caching**.

Try clearing your browser cache.

In Mozilla Firefox, the [keyboard shortcut](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard%20shortcuts) to ***"Reload (override cache)"*** is

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> OR
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, Zach, caching was the real problem. Although Ctrl + F5 (Reload (override cache)) doesn't help but I opened website on clean PC and everything fine there.

Comment: One tip that I've found works on most browsers is to explicitly go to http://example.com/favicon.ico to load the icon into the browser's cache. Then, the next time you go to the web page, the favicon should show up.

Comment: Nither 'Reload (override cache)', with Ctrl + F5 or Ctrl + Shift + R, nor visiting the 'favicon.ico' URL works for me. What works though is restarting the browser. (Tested with Firefox 10.0.2.)

Answer (score 5):

Firefox has separate cache for favicon and this does not work properly. The favicon is not updated easily in firefox. This is a small issue but troubles many of us for long time.

The solution is to clear the favicon cache so that the favicon is update. There are many solutions you can find if you go through the internet or stackoverflow. Most of the solution imvolves deleteing the favicon cache manually or using some plugins. Some saying deleting the file from temp internet files. But there is one really simple and easy way to fix the problem.

1. Type in www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico (or www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon.png, etc.)
2. CTRL + F5 or CTRL + R

This will immediately update the favicon.

This solution was originally posted by 'alex' at this link:
[How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, because I just copy/pasted your code to a blank document, opened with firefox and some random image I renamed to favicon.ico loaded up as the favicon.

Maybe try this?
http://help.godaddy.com/article/4145

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had **another favicon.ico in a web root directory**.

If You have a favicon in template directory "/template/favicon.ico" and another one in "/favicon.ico" firefox will use the favicon from root direcory even though you've used a link for favicon in template folder. **Solution is delete the favicon in root directory.**

My current version of firefox is 58.0b6 (Quantum).

Answer (score 1):

So just had an issue with favicons not showing in Firefox v70.0.1.

Now this will probably only be an issue for a very few people and most likely only if you have modified the **about:config** settings in FF

This issue for me was the setting ***privacy.resistfingerprinting***  was set to **true** on some sites this will block favicons.

The other issue I noticed and what lead me to find out what was causing the issue was using dropzone.js on a site I was creating the uploaded images had a blank preview. The previews are base64 encoded and were being blocked by this.

Like I said most likely wont be an issue for most but wanted to post this somewhere so it may help others that may be facing a similar issue as I did.

See more here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Fingerprinting

And Here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1452391

Answer (score 0):

I am not much of a programmer but I had a similar problem and here is the simple thing that finally worked for me...

I admin several simple websites but Firefox refused to load the favicon of one in particular site. I looked online, tried everything I was able to understand. Nothing worked. The code was exactly the same (copied in fact) from the other websites whose icons worked well.

Eventually it dawned on me that maybe Firefox did not like the path I used to get there. This site was a forwarded URL being hosted on my own domain. (i.e. personal domain is myplace.ca and the favicon that would not load was part of registered URL something.com which was actually located at myplace.ca/PutItHere/) If I used the registered URL (something.com) no favicon. If I use the real path in the browser, suddenly favicon! All I had to do was bookmark the absolute path rather than the registered domain!

Answer (score 0):

I also found, that if you reference the full URL path, you may need to reference the URL WITH www. in it, otherwise it may not load.

Answer (score -1):

Here it's in 2017. Firefox didn't pick up my favicon called "favicon-32x32.png", while Chrome was showing. **I changed the file name to "favicon.png", AND refreshed as folks showed above**, it worked great. I'm using:
Firefox version **55.0**
Chrome version **60.0**