# Unable to set favicon using Jekyll and github pages

Tags: html, jekyll, favicon, github-pages

I am trying to set a `favicon.ico` for my github page, but it doesn't work. When I serve it locally I see the standard "empty" favicon and when I push it I see the facebook icon. Why is it so? I have the right `favicon.ico` in the root directory of my project and I added the line

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

to the relevant `default.html`. You can see the sources here: https://github.com/drorata/drorata.github.io

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I cloned your project from GitHub to take a look at it. After serving it using Jekyll, the favicon did not display, as you noted.

I did some quick testing by converting the favicon file to be a `.png` rather than a `.ico` file and changing the favicon declaration to the following, and that was able to get it to display the favicon.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
```

I tried getting the favicon to work while keeping the `.ico` file format, and was unable to do so at first. However, I did some quick searching and came across this question, [favicon not displayed by Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616016/favicon-not-displayed-by-firefox-i-know-its-been-asked-10000-times).

In that question the asker had a similar issue with the favicon not showing, and was eventually able to come up with a quick fix by adding a `?` to the end of the link to the favicon file in the favicon declaration. I attempted this and it worked. Here is what the favicon declaration would be:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico?">
```

Either of those two methods seem to be able to fix your issue. Personally I'd recommend using the first method, whereby you convert the image to a `.png` file, as it seems a bit simpler and less hacky.

However, if you want to keep the file as a `.ico` file then you should read over the question that I linked to before you attempt the second method, as the accepted answer for the question differed from that solution. Also I'm not sure as to why the second method works, and it does seem a little bit hacky.

Comment: also `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png?">` working for me

Answer (score 18):

I believe, currently, the correct way to do this is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{ "/favicon.png" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" >
```

Assuming you are using a png. The following also worked for me with a .ico instead of .png:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ "/favicon.ico" | prepend: site.baseurl }}" >
```

I was working with Chrome on Linux. Neither Excalibur Zero's answer or Ribtoks answer worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

## Quick solution

Leave the slash out to make the href address relative.

For example:

Change

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
```

to:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

In my [github pages site](https://hustlion.github.io/spanish-cards/) this works perfectly.

## Explanation

Use my site `https://hustlion.github.io/spanish-cards/` as an example:

When you use `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">`, the icon address will be `https://hustlion.github.io/favicon.png`, because the root of the site (as specified by the slash in `/favicon.png`) is `https://hustlion.github.io/`.

However, when you use `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">`, this is relative to the path `https://hustlion.github.io/spanish-cards/`, so the icon address will be resolved properly as `https://hustlion.github.io/spanish-cards/favicon.png`.

## Notes

This path issue happens especially when you are using github pages for your specific repository.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, but it's the best explanation of what's going on. Alternatively, you can add the dot before the slash like so: `href="./favicon.png"`

Answer (score 4):

I use

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/images/favicon.ico" >
```

And I have favicon in folder `images`.

Answer (score 4):

according to documentation:

1) put `favicon.ico` file into `assets/images` folder of jekyll project as `assets/images/favicon.ico`

2) create a `_includes/head_custom.html` file if not yet exists

3) add needed overriding content:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/favicon.ico">
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing above worked for me, but the steps in [this vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v-8_JSydgk) (assuming the minima theme) did.

1) Add `_includes` directory to your project root

- Terminal: find `_includes/head.html` by typing `bundle show minima`
- Copy `_includes/head.html` from finder into your project root

2) Modify `_includes/head.html` to include favicon link

- The following works for me: `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">`
- Important: the `/` in front of `/favicon.png` matters. Without the `/`, your website root will have your favicon but no other endpoints will.

3) Add the `jekyll-seo-tag` plugin to your `_config.yml`. It should look something like this:

```
# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
theme: minima
plugins:
  - jekyll-feed
  - jekyll-seo-tag
```

Answer (score 2):

I got it to working using:

```
<!-- Add favicon -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="{{ '/favicon.png' | relative_url }}" >
```

Notes on the snippet:

1. PNG format for the favicon,
2. a relative URL in the HTML head tag (in [minimia](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) this is `head.html`).
3. Adding [`relative_url`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) tells [Liquid](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/) to prepend the `url` and `baseurl` to the given path.

Comment: It works for me, as well with `.ico` as `.png`, but on Firefox only.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone will be looking for this. Both approaches didn't work for me. But when I appended the `site.url`, it worked

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{{site.url}}/favicon.png">
```

Comment: Perhaps this is because your site field included a base url? Generally you have a site and a base url. www.example-site.com/example-base/ <- your site.url probably looked like this

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add the `favicon.ico` file to the assets folder and reference it as follows:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the images to display and I use markdown for my posts, appending what worked for me so that others may benefit.

`![Description of the image]({{ site.baseurl }}/assets/images/image.png)`

This works both locally and on github pages as well