# Favicon with GitHub Pages

Tags: html, github, favicon, github-pages

I'm hosting a few sites with GitHub Pages (User and Project Pages), but they are not displaying their favicons (in the browser).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">
```

Is the problem that GitHub displays the site with `<frameset>`? I know it's possible to display favicons (at least with Jekyll), but can I display a favicon on it's own?

Comment: If a frameset is used, then the frameset itself must specify the favicon. You can not specify it from one of the inner frames.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to specify the favicon from the frameset with GitHub Pages

Comment: Try if any of this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551501/unable-to-set-favicon-using-jekyll-and-github-pages

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Put this into the `head` part of your webpage:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

It is important to not put the slash before the `favicon.ico` part. Put the `favicon.ico` file in your repository's home directory.

Comment: I also had this problem with my github pages (non jekyll). This answer worked for me in chrome, chromium and firefox. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 13):

It also works with **favicon.png**

```
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  </head>
```

The only problem is the slash `/` in `"/favicon.png"`

However this does not work for sub-pages!

The link should look like this - so you have the favicon on every page:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" 
      href="{{ "/assets/images/favicon.png"  | absolute_url }}">
```

The resolved URL looks like: 
`https://pme123.github.io/scala-adapters/assets/images/favicon.png`

This expects the `favicon.png` in `assets/images` folder of your Jekyll project.

Answer (score 12):

I used

```html
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

as well as

```html
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

or

```html
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{site.url}}/favicon.ico">
```

None of that worked. Finally I got it working by

```html
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?">
```

in fact, seems that any of the above solution with an extra "?" at the end will do the trick.

Comment: ty, worked very well!!! What exactly ? symbol does?

Comment: @ÂngeloPolotto Np! I am not sure, I think it means "query", https://teamtreehouse.com/community/meaning-of-a-question-mark-in-the-url.

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./Images/favicon.ico?">
```

look carefully i added a **"?"** at the end of the href.
if you did something like this , then go to your github.io page and hard reload.
You can use

> ctrl/cmd + shift + r

to hard reload the page . That will clear your cache .
After that I am hopeful that you will see the fav-icon.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would add to this...

If you are using a custom domain name, you can simply put the `favicon.ico` file in the root and browsers will find it. For example if your custom domain is `something.domain.com` the favicon will be in the root and available where browsers expect it at `something.domain.com/favicon.ico`.

However, if you're not using a custom domain, your repo content will be available at `username.github.io/repo-name/`. If you add a favicon to this repo the favicon is available at `username.github.io/repo-name/favicon.ico`, but the browser will look for it at in the root domain at `username.github.io/favicon.ico`.

But!! You can put a favicon at `username.github.io/favicon.ico` by creating a repo named `username.github.io`. If the repo has this exact name GitHub pages will automatically be turned on and the content available at `username.github.io`, kind of like your GitHub home page!

Then if you put a favicon here, all of your GitHub Pages (without custom domains) will automatically use this favicon.

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/63631

Note: This also works for organizations.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure your ico or img is 16 x16 px.  That was my issue also.