# Github website Icon not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, favicon

So i'm making a website using github but the favicon isn't showing. I'm pretty sure im using the right code. `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">` Can any of you help? Give me the right code? I am using bootstrap but i don't think it should change how to add the favicon.

Comment: Did you place the favicon.ico in your repsitory?, did you place this call in the <head>?

Comment: Epig Yes I did.

Comment: To be honest, I dont know but you could try to reload with Shift + F5

Answer (score 1):

You might take alook at [**Adding a favicon to a static HTML page**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Also this might be helpful [**Favicon with GitHub Pages**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037482/favicon-with-github-pages)

If everything is set correctly as you described, you might also try to ctrl/cmd + shift + r to **empty cache**.

Comment: Then You might try to save an image in several formats, e.g. 32x32 or use this tool here: https://realfavicongenerator.net/

Comment: Actually I just opened inspector and clicked "Network" It didn't even try to load it.

Comment: Please make sure that your favicon location is same as in <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/YourPathToFolder/favicon-32x32.png"> or you just have Favicon in root directory.

Comment: If I am correct and https://github.com/mrmajik45/website this is your GitHub repository, changing from <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/website/favicon-32x32.png"> to <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png"> worked for me.

Comment: No I'm doing a hackalong https://github.com/LastMagicHackers/LastMagicHackers.github.io