# Making a website icon in Git

Tags: github

Alright, so I set up a website using Github a while ago. I use it as a showcase for programming projects I'm working on, but that's beside the point. For a while now I've been trying to add an icon to my website, and for the life of me I can't figure out how. Help please.

Comment: Search Google for favicons.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551501/unable-to-set-favicon-using-jekyll-and-github-pages

Comment: i believe this should not be under git tags.

Answer (score 0):

**If by icon you mean the image you see on the browser tab 32x32 pixels**, that is usually in a format called Favicon.
You just need the image of your icon in favicon format (google how to convert an image to favicon and you will find websites that do this for you easily.), add it to your project and then add a tag on your hmtl head:

```
<head>
/* some style tags */
/* THE FOLLOWING IS YOUR 'ICON' */
<link rel="icon" 
  type="image/png" 
  href="./style/images/logo.favicon">

</head>
```

But this question should definitely not be under git tags. You did not mention why one should keep in mind that you are using github.