# Favicon is not appearing on firefox browser for Angular js templates

Tags: angularjs, firefox, favicon

Here is my code snippet how I am including the favicon in my personal website which was built with Angular JS.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico"/>
```

With this code, the favicon is appearing on Chrome and IE browsers. But the favicon is not appearing for Angular JS templates on Firefox browser.

I looked at the similar websites made with Angular JS, the same issue is repeated.

Please refer the following website,

https://www.madewithangular.com/#/

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [favicon not displayed by Firefox (I know, it's been asked 10000 times)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616016/favicon-not-displayed-by-firefox-i-know-its-been-asked-10000-times)

Comment: I looked at the similar websites made with Angular JS, the same issue is repeated.

https://www.madewithangular.com/#/