# Play framework favicon issue

Tags: playframework, favicon

I have searched a lot about this issue, but all solutions in Google forum and here won't fix it, probably because they related to older Play version.

No matter how I modify the link tag

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href='@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.ico")' >
```

or modify route as suggested in other solutions, I always get the default green triangle icon shown in the browser. I even removed this icon but it's still displayed. Browser cache is cleared, I don't know what else I can do. Any help would be great.

Comment: Before trying all solutions, try to eliminate some before... When you browse the source code of you page in the browser and clicks on the `href` of your `link` tag, which picture is displayed ? If it is yours, then your routes are fine.  What about writing `shortcut icon` ?

Comment: what version of play framework do you use?

Comment: It's not the play problem. You run into typical favicon cache problem. There is a lot of questions and solutions depends on OS and browser, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616016/favicon-not-displayed-by-firefox-i-know-its-been-asked-10000-times

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change routes to:

```
GET     /favicon.ico    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/images", file="yourimage.png")
```

Every browser is trying to get favicon by requesting it via /favicon.ico, so you can point it to your page there.

You can request/check your favicon doing this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9000/favicon.ico
```

So if that works (request above) it means that it is most likely cache issue.

You can also read about how to use Assets on here: [The Assets controller](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AssetsOverview#the-assets-controller)

I guess you are using OSX with Chrome and if so you need to clear favicon's cache. Please try next steps:

```
/Users/you/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favcions
```

Restart your Chrome (in case if that does not help, try to delete journal as well and restart Chrome again).

```
/Users/you/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favcions-journal
```

If you use another OS, I'm sure you will find in the google how to clear cache of favicons.

Comment: OSX and Chrome exactly! Thank you!

Comment: @boreas so was it an answer? if so please accept it :)