# how to install sqlite manager addon in firefox quantum (browser version 57)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, firefox

i tried to install sqlite manager addon in firefox but it showing me an error (your Firefox Quantum Browser isn't compatible )

my Firefox Browser version is 57.0.4

Comment: I've got SQLite Manager (my preferred SQLite tool) installed on latest version (27.6.2) of Pale Moon a Firefox offshoot.

Answer (score 4):

> This extension depended upon the interface to sqlite engine embedded
>   in Firefox. As the interface has been removed in Firefox 57, this
>   extension no longer functions. However, the extension can be used on
>   ESR release of Firefox, which can be downloaded at
>   https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/.

Stated on the addon itself. I myself pushed my firefox version back but have also been using DB Browser (http://sqlitebrowser.org/). As its not too bad i may upgrade back to the latest firefox!

Firefox Version Directory: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Hopefully this may help someone fishing around.

Answer (score 1):

You should install older versions of Firefox. Here is link 
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/

Answer (score 1):

An easy work around to browser version issues is to install thunderbird 38 (if you don't use thunderbird for email) https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/ and then install SQLite manager as an extension to thunderbird. I don't use thunderbird for anything else so I set it to no update: options>advanced>update>never check for update.