# How do I change my favicon in Apache 2 on Linux Ubuntu 18.x?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu

My homepage is index.php and I have this in it:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico?v=<?php echo time() ?>" />
```

It is stored in /var/www/html/assets/ico/favicon.ico and is a 16x16 png file.

Despite having that and doing `systemctl` restart apache2 it fails to populate in my Safari
or Chrome browsers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the url pat that you open?
I would suspect on the '..' try to use the absolute path '/assets/ico...".

Comment: Clear your browser cache

Comment: Note: the `<link>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [favicon not displayed by Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616016/favicon-not-displayed-by-firefox)

Comment: Okay, I changed to the absolute path for the favicon.ico and it didn't work:    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/var/www/html/assets/ico/favicon.ico?v=<?php echo time() ?>" />
Also I cleared the cache using this document https://oit.colorado.edu/tutorial/clear-web-browser-cache-safari-6, but neither of the above worked. I also tried restarting the apache instance with systemctl restart apache2

Comment: example.org:xx xx.yy.zz.aa - - [11/Apr/2020:09:19:10 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 488 "http://example.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15"

Comment: So that is being hit as shown in the access log for apache and is not getting favicon.ico served out. It's the old favicon.ico. It is a 16x16 .png file and has been verified to be the new one by copying the icon off-instance and viewing it.

Comment: So it still doesn't work. Ideas? This is the latest apache 2 on the latest linux ubuntu on aws.

Comment: I changed to <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/ico/favicon.ico?v=<?php echo time() ?>"  from what was above and I emptied cache in safari and restarted apache with systemctl restart apache2 and I stopped and started Safari and it does not show me what it showed before but it now shows the Apple default favicon which is the earth but that's not what I want. I have a favicon.ico which is a 16x16 PNG file and it is not showing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <link rel="icon"  type="image/png"  href="/assets/ico/favicon.ico?v=<?php echo time() ?>" />
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.