# Icon not displayed in rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie in rails.

I had put a new favicon.ico in my public folder and deleted the old one.

I have also written a code wherein I have to use the new icon for eg:-

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

  <%  user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] %>
  <%  if /Windows/.match(user_agent).nil? %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application2", :media => "all" %>
  <%  else %>
      <% if user_agent.include? "Safari" and !user_agent.include? "Chrome" %>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "safariwindows", :media => "all" %>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "safariwindows2", :media => "all" %>
      <% else %>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "windowsapplication", :media => "all" %>
          <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "windowsapplication2", :media => "all" %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <!--[if gte IE 7]>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "ie", :media => "all" %>
    <![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag '/video-js/video-js.min' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag '/video-js/video.min' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script>
      pki = "<%= session[:pki] %>"
  </script>
```

I have also cleared cache and also tried in incognito mode but still not working.

Can anyone give any solutions.

Comment: show us what you have done?

Comment: @RSB I have put the above code in application.html

Comment: Sometimes there are weird caching issues which mean the changed favicon doesn't appear.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324456/favicon-not-showing-up

Comment: Are you able to try using a different browser?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Not working in any browser :(

Comment: Are you still seeing the old favicon, or nothing at all?

Comment: @GraemeMcLean Am seeing the old one

Comment: Check my edited answer, you need to put icon in `app/assets/images/` folder and remove the old one from there

Comment: @RSB The old one is in the public directory..My app/assets/images is empty

Comment: have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Please share the actual html source from your browser around the favicon; it still sounds like a caching issue given you are seeing the old icon.

Comment: @GraemeMcLean When I click on the favicon.ico in my browser console it is showing me the new logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Checkout this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#File_format_support, all modern browsers needs this tag to render favicon. Also, if you think this adds value to your question, you might upvote. J:

Answer (score 1):

Make sure name of the icon is `favicon` and try this erb tag under `<head>` tag in `application.html.erb` layout, Put your icon in `app/assets/images/` **and not in** `public` folder.

Remove

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

and add

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

Comment: are you sure name of the icon is `favicon`?

Comment: where is your favicon.ico image?

Comment: It should reside in `app/assets/images/`

Answer (score 0):

Store your icon image in **`app/assets/images/favicon.ico`** folder. then wherever you want generally in application layout file under the app/view/layouts

put this code

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

check this **[link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag)** for more details

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't answer the question of the OP.

Comment: @Iceman : Ya I realized that it was not about image_tag but about favicon_link_tag. I have edited my answer. Now it may be correct. not sure