# Rails Admin - How to add favicon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

How to specify the favicon for the admin panel? Should it be specified somewhere in the configuration? No information regarding this is given in the [wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just throw a `favicon.ico` in your `/public` folder.

Comment: I already have a favicon.ico in my public folder but its not getting displayed.

Comment: In my experience it takes a bit of time to cache the icon.

Comment: Chrome was the culprit. I cleared the cache, restarted the server. Now its working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Add below snippet in your template's header tag.

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538500/icon-not-displayed-in-rails-website/23539283#23539283).

Answer (score 0):

try `<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>`

and moving the `favicon.ico` to the /public/images directory.