# Favicon doesnt update

Tags: favicon

I copied a new favicon to the server , but the old one shows up. Could another one have precedence even though this one is called in the head of the page?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

The image is a sibling of the page.

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Answer (score 0):

I always find browsers cache favicons fairly aggressively, so check this first.

Secondly, different browsers look for a favicon slightly differently. Explained at the bottom here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Providing you have the favicon in your web root, you'll keep the majority happy.