# Favicon.ico is not working...is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: html, favicon

Hey ya'll I have this line of code here for my favicon.ico file

```
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://www.myurl.com/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/favicon.ico" />
```

The file is in the right place and I cleared my cache and restarted my browser and its not working, it is also placed inside my header tags.

Comment: I've found that browsers do weird caching on favicons... Have you tried a different browser? Also, have a read over [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh) and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks Christian...it did work on other browsers!

Comment: Yep, sorry about that. Didn't realize the base URL. Haha sorry! If you copy/paste the URL of the ICO into the address bar, does it show it (in the problematic browser)? What browser is it not working in anyways?

Comment: i was firefox, but now it is working :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/yourAssetFilePath/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
<link rel="icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i just have

```
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

works for me,
it does do some funny caching thing though, and i think it's in IE that you need to bookmark the page before it appears?