# Chrome browser reload options new feature

Tags: google-chrome

I found this new feature in Chrome today. When you hover over the refresh button you get this tooltip saying: "Reload this page, hold to see more options" and when I do it I get these three awesome options.

1. Normal Reload
2. Hard Reload
3. Empty Cache and Hard Reload

*I believe the last one is a very useful option.*

But the problem is I can't see it consistently across all tabs/web pages. Only local files and even its not consistent.
Anybody here knows how this is enabled/disabled?

*P.s. I tried googling but didn't find anything related. Either way it's a great feature I believe for all developers out there.*

[image: Google chrome reload option]

Comment: NOTE: on Mac you right click the reload button.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

If you have the Developer Tools open (F12 / Ctrl-Shift-I / Cmd + Opt + I, Chrome Menu → More tools → Developer Tools), then the reload menu can appear.

[image]

Comment: But where is this document my colleague stumbled across this today and we love it. It should be shouted to the world =)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on OS X using Chrome 23.0.1271.95. Is it a Windows only feature?

Comment: Yes, its only a windows feature. I could not get it to work on mac either, however there are many add on's available for Chrome which can replicate this same feature.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu, too.

Comment: This thing is so, so awesome. It'd be nice to have a keybind for the "total piece-of-mind" cachewipe, though.

Comment: FYI, you can disable cache as long as you have dev tools open on the current page. just click the cog icon on the bottom-right and check disable cache. saves some heck of time.

Comment: @UmurKontacı `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`DEL`

Comment: On OS X you can use cmd-shift-r

Comment: This works for OSX. Just have your developer tools open on the page you want to reload and hold the button down, and you'll receive.

Comment: `F12` (equals to `Ctrl + Shift + I`) works as well on Windows. BTW, `Cmd + Opt + I` for Mac.

Comment: Can you explain with image since I cannot find `Tools` in ubuntu.

Comment: with dev tools open, neither control-click, option-click, nor command-click will work. however with dev tools open you can "right" click (two-finger click) on the refresh button, or you can click and hold. Chrome v59.0.3071.115 for macOS Sierra

Comment: Not sure why, but sometimes these options appear when not in developer mode. This led me to believe that sometimes the page was cached and sometimes not, that's why I could access them outside of dev mode. But, that's not the case. No clue why there is the inconsistent access outside of dev mode. Just open dev mode and the options will consistently be present.

Comment: @UmurKontacı I could not find the icon on bottom right, but your comment gave me the idea, +1 for that. We have a similar link on SO, explaining the steps: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development]

Comment: @Jiten they've changed it since I wrote it. Now it's a checkbox in the top bar of the network tab.

Answer (score -4):

To refresh the Chrome Browser screen on an android cell phone

1. Press and hold the URL address at the top of the screen
2. The address will highlight and the keyboard will reappear.
3. Hit the return (or enter) arrow

and the browser will go out to the highlighted url (refreshed).

Comment: this is chrome mobile, not pc. and I think we all know how to refresh. the question is about hard refresh.

Comment: an attempt was made . . .