# ui-grid symbols issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I am using AngularJs ui-grid http://ui-grid.info/.

While implementing, I get something which you can see in the following img in right corner of the cell instead of dropdown symbols.

[image]

Which files to include to solve this bug?

Comment: more likely some fonts files are missing check your console for errors

Comment: If you use `ui-grid - v4.6.6`, you need to put `ui-grid.ttf` and `ui-grid.woff` into folder `fonts`. So the structure of directory will looks like this:
`ui-grid.min.css`
fonts  # <-  this is a folder
    `ui-grid.ttf`
    `ui-grid.woff`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to download the font files:

- `ui-grid.woff`
- `ui-grid.eot`
- `ui-grid.svg`
- `ui-grid.ttf`

from [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release). And move them where your `ui-grid.min.css` lives.

Comment: I added .woff & .tff files & included them by `<script>` tag...It gives me error - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: I just added `.woff & .ttf` files..!

Comment: @Anup You need to add all files because they have been used for cross-browser compatability.

Comment: @RahilWazir if I have changed the location in css file the icons are not appearing, any concerns?

Comment: @VellankiGaneshBabu You need to alter the location inside `ui-grid.min.css` file

Comment: @oCcSking Try removing cache and make sure the files is place like [this structure](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30)

Comment: 10x @RahilWazir for the fast reply .. i always [clear cache](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12633425/1509853) and i take all files from [hare](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.0.3)

Comment: @oCcSking Inspect your network tab that those fonts are being loaded

Comment: @RahilWazir I do not see them there .. However, I have another font that is not listed there, and still is active

Comment: @rahilwazir Thanks, should this files be referred in the index.html. I have these files in bower_components but not referring anywhere. And i have the same issue raised by OP at some instances in some envrionment.

Comment: The fix for me was to manually add ui-grid.woff file to solution

Comment: What is the impact if i omit ui-grid.svg file? as that file is not under MIT license?

Answer (score 6):

Please include ui-grid CSS file by this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/release/ui-grid-unstable.css">
```

and ommit the script tag from the Authors Tutorial or Api

```
<script src="/release/ui-grid-unstable.css"></script>
```

for eg (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting)

Answer (score 4):

I would just like to add [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942350/how-to-include-ui-grid-font-files-into-the-project/30371632#30371632) (stolen verbatim from panciz) for the folks using Grunt who would like to have these automatically copied.  This needs to be placed in your Gruntfile.js:

```
copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [
           ...
        //font di ui grid
         {
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              dest: 'dist/styles/',
              src: ['bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.ttf',
                    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.woff',
                    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.eot',
                    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.svg'
                    ]
            }
    ]},
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to look at a recently added tutorial: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/116_fonts_and_installation

This covers how to install the fonts correctly, and a little bit of trouble shooting.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the issue is modify the CSS class as follows

```
.ui-grid-icon-down-dir:before {
  content: '\25bc';
}
.ui-grid-icon-up-dir:before {
  content: '\25b2';
}

.ui-grid-selection-row-header-buttons.ui-grid-row-selected:before{
    content:'\2714' !important;
}
.ui-grid-all-selected:before{
    content:'\2714' !important;
}
```

Comment: Where did you find these unicode values?

Comment: https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode

Answer (score 1):

Try to include in your project :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bower-ui-grid/master/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `gulp`, add this task.

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {

  // Copy font files needed for angular-ui-grid
  gulp.src(['bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.ttf',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.woff',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.eot',
    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.svg'
  ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles/'))

  // Other style tasks here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'bower_components/angular-ui-grid',
            src: ['*.eot', '*.svg', '*.ttf', '*.woff'],
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
          }
add this code to grunt file at  copy: {
      dist: {

Comment: In gruntfile.js

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ui-grid - v4.6.6`, you need to put `ui-grid.ttf` and `ui-grid.woff` into folder `fonts`. So the structure of directory will looks like this:

```
ui-grid.min.css
fonts  # <--  this is a folder
    ui-grid.ttf  # <-- in fonts folder
    ui-grid.woff  # <-- in fonts folder
```

Comment: But if you install ui-grid (v4.6.6) from npm, the fonts folder is already there. I've been having this issue since I upgraded to a newer version; I check the angular-ui-grid folder in node_modules, and the fonts folder is already there ??? ...

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer to hopefully save someone a headache. I had this problem and went through all the steps I could find. However, the problem wasn't file location, etc, my issue is the .woff file was corrupted. I downloaded the fonts to my local machine and ftp'd them to the server. Unfortunately, the .woff on the server ended up in a bad state and was bombing the @font-face declaration. Although this particular problem doesn't mention any console warnings/errors, they will match issues resolved by adding the fonts to grunt/gulp/etc.

I don't recall the error in Chrome, but in Firefox it was:

> downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer

So, if you've gone through the hoops and nothing seems to work, check if the font files are correct because my FTP failed for .woff and it resulted in the same Korean characters, etc.