# How to include ui-grid font files into the project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have been stuck with anjularjs ui-grid, it's showing some Chinese symbols in place of icons. After digging about it I get to know I have to use some font-files provided by ui-grid team, I downloaded the files and included them into my project but still m not getting the correct icon images and fonts, how to include these files into the project?

These are the file names which I downloaded and included in my project:

```
1 ui-grid.eot 
2 ui-grid.svg
3 ui-grid.ttf
4 ui-grid.woff
```

Comment: Are those files in the same directory as your ui-grid-unstable.css file? On my setup they are and I don't see these other symbols. I don't recall having to do anything else.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, now it is rectified as follows

I updated the Ui-grid with either latest stable version(v3.0.0-rc.3) or the unstable version(v3.0.0-rc.16).

then
place the font files all in the same directory as your ui-grid.css lives, like this

```
app
- lib
  - ui-grid.js
  - ui-grid.css
  - ui-grid.eot
  - ui-grid.svg
  - ui-grid.ttf
  - ui-grid.woff
```

or

you can open the CSS and change the file path to the relative location in @font-face url's

check here
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/116_fonts_and_installation

Comment: The simple solution to this problem is dont use CDN,s build the files locally into your project.

Comment: here the question was user downloaded the files but don't know the relative file path replacement. I had given the answer by mapping your relative path in CSS file

Comment: PF answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651918/ui-grid-symbols-issue

Comment: What about licensing? Those file are not licensed under MIT (ui-grid.svg for eg.) , Can we use it for commercial purpose?

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Grunt I had to add

```
copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [
           ...
        //font di ui grid
         {
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              dest: 'dist/styles/',
              src: ['bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.ttf',
                    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.woff',
                    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.eot',
                    'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.svg'
                    ]
            }
    ]},
```

to the `Gruntfile.js` In order to copy the `ui-grid` fonts in the `style`  directory.

Answer (score 2):

With Gulp you can add this task into build.js file

```
gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
   gulp.src('./bower_components/angular-ui-grid/**/*.{ttf,woff}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/styles/')));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Gulp and I added a `fonts:dev` task to be added as a dep to my `serve` task:

```
 gulp.task('fonts:dev', function () {
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
      .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
      .pipe($.flatten())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.tmp + '/serve/fonts/'));
  });
```

This solved it for me. More context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311553/copy-angular-ui-grid-fonts-into-tmp-fonts).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late but I just want to share my answer. I use bower to install ui-grid and gruntjs to load files. Its almost the same with Panciz answer but change it to `*.{ttf,woff,eot,svg}` for getting all font files needed without specifying them.

add this in copy:

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [
      //other files here
      , {
          expand: true,
          flatten: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/app', //change destination base to your file structure
          src: [
            '*.{ttf,woff,eot,svg}',
            'bower_components/angular-ui-grid/*',
          ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install ui grid using 'bower install' than the files should be installed in their proper location. The problem we had is that we're using ui-router, which requires all requests to be rewritten to index.html.  We had to add the font extensions to our rewrite rules so that Angular could load them. We're using a middleware plugin for running locally. On Apache/Nginx server the concept is the same.

```
middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          modRewrite(['!\\.html|\\.js|\\.svg|\\.woff|\\.ttf|\\.eot|\\.css|\\.png$ /index.html [L]']),
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project i usually use grunt to put fonts files in `build/assets` directory and vendors files in `build/vendor/lib-name` directory.

But ui-grid.css have relative path to get font file and doesn't have any mode to configure a different location without modify your css file. But i think that it's not a good idea because then you need to change this file for each vendor update.

So you can setup your grunt to put this particular font with your vendor files too.

This is your `build.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    vendor_files: {
        ...
        js: [
            'vendor/angular/bundle.min.js',
            'vendor/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js',
        ],
        css: [
            'vendor/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.css',
        ],
        uigrid_fonts: [
            'vendor/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.woff',
            'vendor/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.ttf',
            'vendor/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.eot',
            'vendor/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.svg',
        ],
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then on your `Gruntfile.js` you can manage this file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    //.. other require

    var userConfig = require('./build.config.js');
    var taskConfig = {
        copy: {
            //.. other copy task
            build_vendor_fonts: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: [ '<%= vendor_files.fonts %>' ],
                        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/assets/fonts/',
                        cwd: '.',
                        expand: true,
                        flatten: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            build_uigrid_font: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: [ '<%= vendor_files.uigrid_fonts %>' ],
                        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
                        cwd: '.',
                        expand: true,
                    }
                ]
            },
            build_vendor_css: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: [ '<%= vendor_files.css %>' ],
                        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
                        cwd: '.',
                        expand: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            build_appjs: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: [ '<%= app_files.js %>' ],
                        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
                        cwd: '.',
                        expand: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            build_vendorjs: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: [ '<%= vendor_files.js %>' ],
                        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
                        cwd: '.',
                        expand: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
    };

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean', 
        'concat:build_css', 
        'copy:build_vendor_fonts', 
        'copy:build_uigrid_font',
        'copy:build_vendor_css', 
        'copy:build_appjs', 
        'copy:build_vendorjs', 
        'index:build'
    ]);

    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same answer as Panciz and Vicruz, but I specified the relevant directories slightly differently:

```
copy: {
     dist: {
        files: [{
           // other files here...
        }, {
           expand : true,
           cwd : 'bower_components/angular-ui-grid',
           dest : '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles',
           src : ['*.eot','*.svg','*.ttf','*.woff']
        }]
     },
```