# Copy angular-ui-grid fonts into .tmp/fonts

Tags: angularjs, fonts, gulp, angular-ui-grid

I was experiencing a [known](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1786) [issue](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/116_fonts_and_installation) with [Angular UI Grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid) where some of my fonts would look Korean in production.

I applied [a certain fix](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1786#issuecomment-75791745) by adding the following CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ui-grid';
  src: url('../fonts/ui-grid.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ui-grid.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.ttf?') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ui-grid.svg?#ui-grid') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This fixed the problem in production, but now in development I get these errors in the browser console:

> GET http://localhost:9000/fonts/ui-grid.woff
>
> GET http://localhost:9000/fonts/ui-grid.ttf? 404 (Not Found)

I'm using Gulp as my build tool. I can get the errors to go away by adding a `fonts` directory to `.tmp/serve` and manually copying `bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.*` there, but this of course isn't an acceptable permanent solution.

My Gulp configuration already copies my font files to `public/fonts` in production. How can I achieve something similar in development?

Here's my `gulp/build.js`. I'm a Gulp novice.

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: ['gulp-*', 'main-bower-files', 'uglify-save-license', 'del']
});

module.exports = function(options) {
  gulp.task('partials', ['markups'], function () {
    return gulp.src([
      options.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.html',
      options.tmp + '/serve/{app,components}/**/*.html'
    ])
      .pipe($.minifyHtml({
        empty: true,
        spare: true,
        quotes: true
      }))
      .pipe($.angularTemplatecache('templateCacheHtml.js', {
        module: 'freightVerify'
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.tmp + '/partials/'));
  });

  gulp.task('html', ['inject', 'partials'], function () {
    var partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(options.tmp + '/partials/templateCacheHtml.js', { read: false });
    var partialsInjectOptions = {
      starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
      ignorePath: options.tmp + '/partials',
      addRootSlash: false
    };

    var htmlFilter = $.filter('*.html');
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');
    var assets;

    return gulp.src(options.tmp + '/serve/*.html')
      .pipe($.inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
      .pipe(assets = $.useref.assets())
      .pipe($.rev())
      .pipe(jsFilter)
      .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
      .pipe($.uglify({ preserveComments: $.uglifySaveLicense })).on('error', options.errorHandler('Uglify'))
      .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
      .pipe(cssFilter)
      .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/', '../fonts/'))
      .pipe($.csso())
      .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
      .pipe(assets.restore())
      .pipe($.useref())
      .pipe($.revReplace())
      .pipe(htmlFilter)
      .pipe($.minifyHtml({
        empty: true,
        spare: true,
        quotes: true,
        conditionals: true
      }))
      .pipe(htmlFilter.restore())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dist + '/'))
      .pipe($.size({ title: options.dist + '/', showFiles: true }));
  });

  // Only applies for fonts from bower dependencies
  // Custom fonts are handled by the "other" task
  gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
      .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
      .pipe($.flatten())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dist + '/fonts/'));
  });

  gulp.task('other', function () {
    return gulp.src([
      options.src + '/**/*',
      '!' + options.src + '/**/*.{html,css,js,scss,jade}'
    ])
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dist + '/'));
  });

  gulp.task('clean', function (done) {
    $.del([options.dist + '/', options.tmp + '/'], done);
  });

  gulp.task('config', function() {
    gulp.src(options.src + '/app/config/config.json')
      .pipe($.ngConfig('freightVerify', {
        wrap: '(function () {\n\'use strict\';\n/*jshint ignore:start*/\n return <%= module %> /*jshint ignore:end*/\n})();',
        createModule: false,
        environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.src + '/app/config'));
  });

  gulp.task('build', ['config', 'html', 'fonts', 'other']);
};
```

And here's the `gulpfile` itself, if it helps:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var _ = require('lodash');
var wrench = require('wrench');

var options = {
  src: 'src',
  dist: '../public',
  tmp: '.tmp',
  e2e: 'e2e',
  errorHandler: function(title) {
    return function(err) {
      gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[' + title + ']'), err.toString());
      this.emit('end');
    };
  }
};

wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file)(options);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
  gulp.start('build');
});

gulp.task('heroku:production', function() {
  gulp.start('build');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up while a solution that works, although it's not very DRY. I hope someone else suggests a better solution.

```
  // This is the original fonts task
  gulp.task('fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
      .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
      .pipe($.flatten())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.dist + '/fonts/'));
  });

  // This is my new task, only slightly different
  gulp.task('fonts:dev', function () {
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
      .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
      .pipe($.flatten())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(options.tmp + '/serve/fonts/'));
  });
```

I added the `fonts:dev` task as shown above, and I added it as a dep to my `serve` task.