# gulp font task do not add roboto-fontface files into dist folder

Tags: angularjs, fonts, gulp

I am using `gulp serve:dist` to build the angular project but when index page render it gives 404 error for all roboto fonts. see [image: 404 errrors]

Search many [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311553/copy-angular-ui-grid-fonts-into-tmp-fonts) and on github but none of them is working so far. Here are my folder structure and code

*/app/*

```
|-- bower_components
|-- bower.json
|-- dist
|-- gulp
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- karma.conf.js
|-- node_modules
|-- package.json
|-- README.md
|-- src
```

*/bower_components/roboto-fontface/*

```
.
|-- bower.json ( content of this file is written below )
|-- css
|   |-- mixins.less
|   |-- mixins.scss
|   |-- roboto
|   |   |-- less
|   |   |   |-- roboto-fontface-black-italic.less
|   |   |   |-- ....  ....
|   |   |   `-- roboto-fontface-thin.less
|   |   |-- roboto-fontface.css
|   |   `-- sass
|   |       |-- roboto-fontface-black-italic.scss
|   |       |-- .... ....
|   |       `-- roboto-fontface-thin.scss
|   `-- roboto-condensed
|       |-- less
|       |   |-- roboto-condensed-fontface-bold-italic.less
|       |   |-- .... ....
|       |   `-- roboto-condensed-fontface-regular.less
|       |-- roboto-condensed-fontface.css
|       `-- sass
|           |-- roboto-condensed-fontface-bold-italic.scss
|           |-- .... ....
|           `-- roboto-condensed-fontface.scss
|-- fonts
|   |-- roboto
|   |   |-- Roboto-Black{/.eot,/.svg,/.ttf,/.woff,/.woff2}
|   |   |-- Roboto-Regular{/.eot,/.svg,/.ttf,/.woff,/.woff2}
|   |   `-- Roboto-Thin{/.eot,/.svg,/.ttf,/.woff,/.woff2}
|   `-- roboto-condensed
|       |-- Roboto-Condensed-Bold{/.eot,/.svg,/.ttf,/.woff,/.woff2}
|       `-- Roboto-Condensed-Regular{/.eot,/.svg,/.ttf,/.woff,/.woff2}
```

#### /bower_components/roboto-fontface/bower.json

```
{
    "name": "roboto-fontface",
    "description": "A simple package providing the Roboto fontface.",
    "version": "0.5.0",
    "main": [
        "./css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css",
        "./css/roboto-condensed/roboto-condensed-fontface.css",
        "./fonts/roboto/*.*",
        "./fonts/roboto-condensed/*.*"
    ],
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "test",
        "tests"
    ]
}
```

here is complete [*gulp/build.js*](http://pastebin.com/b5Nc61Ya)  and relevant font task is

```
gulp.task('fonts', function () {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
    .pipe($.filter('**/*.{otf,eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/')));
});
```

trial 1

```
gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
   return gulp.src('../bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts/**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}')
   .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/fonts/')));
});
```

and

```
gulp.task('build', ['html', 'fonts', 'copyfonts', 'other']);
```

this does not work

trial 2

```
gulp.task('fonts:dev', function () {
    return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles())
      .pipe($.filter('**/*.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
      .pipe($.flatten())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/fonts/')));
});
```

but this will add font-awesome and glyphicon  .{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2} files into serve/fonts/  which are already in *dist/fonts* folder

trial 3

added in main *app/bower.json*

```
"roboto-fontface": {
      "main": [
        "css/roboto-condensed/less/roboto-condensed-fontface.less"
      ]
    },
```

but still not working

---

#### UPDATE (working)

```
// copy Roboto fonts into Roboto Directory
gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
  return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles().concat('bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts/roboto/*'))
    .pipe($.filter('{Roboto-Black,Roboto-Bold,Roboto-Medium,Roboto-Regular}.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
    .pipe($.flatten())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/Roboto')));
});
```

Above is working fine but here I need to copy fronts into */fonts/Roboto*  folder?

If I do not add *Roboto* folder in `gulp.dest` than 404 error comes as it is looking fonts in *fonts/Roboto* folder?

where to change this *fonts/Roboto* folder name to to default */fonts* folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here how I did to achieve this. first update the version to **roboto-fontface 0.7.0** and apply below steps

1. added in **/app/bower.json**

   ```
   "overrides": {
      "roboto-fontface": {
         "main": [
             "css/roboto/less/roboto-fontface.less"
         ]
      }
   }
   ```
2. in **app/index.less**

   ```
   @import "../../bower_components/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/less/roboto-fontface.less";
   @roboto-font-path: "../../bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts";
   ```
3. add below line in `html` task here

   ```
   .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts/', '../fonts/'))
   .pipe($.replace('../../bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/', '../fonts/'))
   ```
4. add a new gulp task **copyfonts** which will copy Roboto fonts into Roboto Directory

   ```
   gulp.task('copyfonts', function() {
   return gulp.src($.mainBowerFiles().concat('bower_components/roboto-fontface/fonts/Roboto/*'))
   .pipe($.filter('{Roboto-Thin,Roboto-Medium,Roboto-Bold,Roboto-Regular}.{eot,svg,ttf,woff,woff2}'))
   .pipe($.flatten())
   .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.dist, '/fonts/Roboto/')));
    });
   ```
5. add these task in below order

   ```
   gulp.task('war', ['html', 'fonts', 'copyfonts', 'other'], function () {
   ```