# ng-grid is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement angularjs grid. i followed all insttructions but its not loading properly

[image]

**Code for angular app**

`var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);`

**Code for controller**

`app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {`

$scope.myData = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];
}]);

Comment: Please show me your `ng-grid` on client side. and please show me your full code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is shown thus, it should have to do with your css files. Please be sure you have added ui-grid.css (and their dependencies) properly.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651918/ui-grid-symbols-issue)

Comment: Yes i have added css also.

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.'
 

.ui-grid {

ui-grid.css (line 1)
ui-grid controller
angular.js (line 11562)
Creating raise event method core.raise.renderingComplete
angular.js (line 11562)

Comment: probably you include the css file using ´<script></script>´ . change it by ´<link> </link>´