# ngQuickDate showing Korean characters on date range

Tags: angularjs

I'm using [ngQuickDate](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate) in my angularJS application. When I pick an absolute date range, I see Korean characters instead of A.M or P.M.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure where these characters are coming from. I'm also using ui-grid that has a similar problem: [ui-grid symbols issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651918/ui-grid-symbols-issue) but I'm not sure if they're related since I only see the Korean characters in ng-quickDate. I'm using Angular 1.4 and the docs for ngQuickDate:https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate say that it's only compatible with Angular 1.2, although the functionality of ngQuickDate seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the default Javascript `Date.parse()` function when parsing the Date/Time was causing the Korean characters to show instead of a.m. or p.m. See the "Smarter Date/Time parsing" section [here](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate).

I added [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) as a dependency in my angularJS app. In the Library code for [`ngQuickDate`](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate), I wrapped the date in a `moment()` function, and that correctly parsed the Date/time to show a.m / p.m instead of the Korean characters.