# favicon not showing website in chrome or firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, favicon

Why isn't this website's favicon showing in chrome or firefox?

It is in the root of the server at http://the-irf.com/favicon.ico and is in the .ico format so it should be supported by those browsers.

Comment: how is it put on page? cause if you are talking about http://the-irf.com then there's no favicon in page source

Comment: Try do a Hard reload in Chrome. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not a browser will request favicon.ico by default, without it being referenced in the source, likely varies from browser to browser. If you'd like browsers to definitely use it, then include the following within the `head` of the HTML:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://the-irf.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Ah, I see. But what about in chrome in [this site](http://guggle.co/). It is not working even though it has been pointed to explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure that the file format is correct? How was the icon created? The source looks okay.

Comment: I think so. I created it here: http://converticon.com/. How else should I or how should I be converting it properly? I run Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

call it explicitly

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

http://www.html-kit.com/favicon/validator/

Comment: Ah, I see. But what about in chrome at [this site](http://guggle.co/). It is not working even though it has been pointed to explicitly.

Comment: Exactly my point, it is not working in chrome even though it has been explicitly defined in the source just like your answer. How can it be fixed so that it shows?

Answer (score 0):

When writing a web server I came across a possible answer to this question. If chrome requests a favicon and receives a 404 Not Found response then it will no longer request it. Even if you clear your cache / hard reload it will no longer ask for it. The other answer's responses work as well as: [How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)