# Unable to update web page's title icon

Tags: asp.net

I have add an Icon using the below line ,

```
link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"
```

After some time I trying to update or replace the icon with some other, but I cant it shows the old icon only.

How to remove the icon or update

Comment: have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, I have done it through Tools->Delete Browsing History and select all check boxes ....

Comment: This question has been asked before, you can see the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: i have typed www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico and clear the history data.. Now the icon removed. But I am waiting for some time is it come again after some time in any case. Hope it will get solved. Thanks to every one...

Answer (score 0):

Use this line

```
link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=1"
```

It will refresh your favicon.

Answer (score -1):

```
                var IconFile = "http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico";

                document.write("<link src='");
                document.write(IconFile);
                document.write("?t=" + new Date().getTime());
                document.write("' alt='' style='width: 57px; height: 57px;' id='demo-icon-image' />");
            </script>
```

Comment: A comment on why to use javascript and how to use it would be nice. An answer with only code in it is considered a low-quality answer