# Favicon doesn't refreshes even after forced refresh

Tags: html, favicon

I built two websites on my localhost. I used one favicon for the first website.

Later when i started developing the second website. I copied first website and started working on it. I changed code and files for the second website.

But when I run the second website on my server why does it shows favicon from the first website?

I tried force refresh it, clear cache. But nothings helping.

Comment: Only thing I suspect is the URL's

Comment: Clear cookies then refresh your page

Comment: clear your cache might help

Comment: Are both websites running off localhost/ ? You should make a named virtual host for each, so there is no confusion :)

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard yeah both running on same local. Even i thought the same but problem was still there when i uploaded it on server.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache but you might also consider setting up a named virtual host both sites.