# Favicon not showing in Symfony2 using Xampp

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, twig, favicon

I'm trying to modify the Xampp favicon and it's being impossible.

At first I changed the xampp default favicon `htdocs/favicon.ico`, and It still showing the orange "X".

Then I thought it could be the configuration of my symfony project.
So I went to `myProyect/web` and overwrited the symfony favicon.ico with mine.
I have to clarify that before I made this, it didn't show the "SF" black favicon.

And tryed to add the fav icon line to both "base.html.twig" and "layout.html.twig":

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />`

And also tryed this:

`<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />`

The favicon file is located in-> htdocs/MyProyect/web/favicon.ico

But I have no clue why is still showing the Xampp default icon...
I have erased symfony cache, and both chrome and firefox cache, and still doesn't work.

I'll apreciate some help with this, I'm a Symfony noob and some parts of it is driving me crazy.

Thank to you all.

Comment: Have you tried another browser you never use. I always have this issue with Favicons and have to use say Safari to confirm it is working. I understand you have cleared the cache of you other browsers, but the fact that you have changed the default xampp favicon and it still appears makes me think this.

Comment: is the path in the generated html correct? did you reload the page with [SHIFT] + [F5] or what ever to reload without reading from cache?

Comment: @ferdynator CTRL + F5 on Windows

Comment: I have just replaced the favicon in htdocs, still showing in Chrome as the original, but Firefox is now showing me the right one. Not matter how many times I refresh, chrome continues to show me the wrong one.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: @The-Humble-Rat Of course I had tested it with other browser (Firefox) even with the useless IE. And I always use CTRL+F5 to refresh + erase cache in both browsers.  But I think is something related with Xampp installed services, because when I go to the Xampp folder and overwrite xampp icon with mine, the preview of the icon changes again for the xampp one O_o''... is crazy.   I remember it happened to me when I used xampp a few years ago, but I can't remember how I made it out.

Comment: for the record, I made the changes even stopping and closing xampp in windows.

Comment: I feel like an idiot... even erasing all cache and all this stuff. I made it with this:

1. type in www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico

2. push enter

3. ctrl+f5

4. done

5. Restart Browser (IE)

Comment: Thanks to the-Humble-Rat source, the second choosed comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Answer (score 7):

Your favicon should be in web folder root.
If not loading new favicon then use query string like this.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}?v=2" />
```