# change favicon per route node express

Tags: node.js, dynamic, express, routes, favicon

I created an app using express to host multiple signup pages. I would like each signup page to have it's own favicon; however, express seems to require a favicon in the configuration otherwise it uses it's default. My html favicon tags don't override the one cached by express.

Comment: See if [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh?rq=1) is helpful. I am not sure you'd be successful doing this server-side alone, given how browsers seem to handle favicon caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the favicon middleware, because it assumes you have 1 favicon for the whole site (like you're supposed to.)

That said, you can force the favicon to be different things on each page.

Sign Up:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/public/favicon-signup.ico">
```

Sign In:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/public/favicon-signin.ico">
```

In your templating, for example jade, you'll want to leave a `block favicon` to be able to use a layout and still have the link in the head of the page.

Use [static middleware](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#directory) to serve the favicons out of the public folder.

Comment: If I don't use the favicon middleware the default express favicon is shown even if I added the favicon tags in my html.  How would I use static middleware to remove this default behavior?