# Force show favicon on Google Drive hosted websited

Tags: google-drive-api, favicon

I put the favicon in the html like this:

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico' />
```

...but when visited with Google Chrome it shows the logo of Google Drive instead of my favicon.

This doesn't happen on Firefox, only on Chrome. So is there any way how to force MY favicon to show on google drive hosted webpages? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a querystring to my filename worked for me:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

See: "[How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116701/2743810)"

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Drive Product Forums:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="x-icon">
```

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/03pmip5YJiY/WVTn_2qGm4cJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a [Styleshout](http://www.styleshout.com/) template and hosting it on Google Drive. The code they have in the header of the index.html file is:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" >
```

And whatever I put as "favicon.png" in the root directory of the site shows up as the favicon.

I added this code to the header of a different site that was displaying the Google Drive icon and it started displaying whatever I put as "favicon.png" instead.

They are using a .png file instead of an .ico file, but it works. Furthermore, you can use other sizes of .png files, rather than just 16x16.

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct your url with the **folder id** that contains your index.html (and js, favicon, css) instead of the file id of the index.html (I suppose that this is what you are doing because i had the same problem).

No use this id:

[image]

Use this instead:
[image]

Where "casacas" is the folder where you put the index.html file and the favicon.ico (plus js, css, images) and configured with public access.
[image]

Then, in your html simple use:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

[image]