# No way to show up favicon.ico

Tags: php, html, favicon

i have this in the head of the document:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

I read all I could about it here, but that didn't help and that's why I'm asking again. I'm positive that it wasn't a typo - PHP file_exists finds the ico file fine, but none of the browsers show it... What could be the reason? This domain is new but after I checked the DNS records they are refreshed and are OK. I cleared local cache and deleted tmp files... You can see it live at http://mybestday.eu

Comment: Favicons are heavily cached, in a different place than normal cache. You can't clear favicon cache.

Comment: did you visit that site - do you see favicon than?

Comment: oh, really.. than sorry for bother you guys but I tested on 2 pc-s but connected to same router.. thank you and sorry !

Comment: No, others may have the same issue. Don't delete, I'll post an community wiki answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Favicons are stored in a special cache. That cache lasts a long time (days to weeks) and can't be cleared by clearing the normal content cache. You could test favicons on a remote computer (like browserstack) or just wait 'till the cache expires.

Or, see the next answers for (ugly) workarounds:

Comment: Is it possible to test using something like incognito mode?

Comment: @88MPG Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I wouldn't say ugly. As a matter of fact every website I run into uses cache busting for almost every design pattern out there.

Comment: It looks cleaner without it. Even if everyone poops, it's not beautiful.

Comment: @bjb568 Think about it this way: This is useful when updates occur on CSS/Images/JS. You don't want the user to have to clear their cache every time you make an update to your system. If anything I think this is a necessary step.

Comment: I agree, it's a good solution. And necessary. But so is pooping.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear your favicon by forcing your browser to re-cache it using a cache buster:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2" />
```

Every time you change the image, change the version (?v=) to an increment (3, 4, ...).

Here is a related discussion on this issue: [How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

[image: So far i can see it works ;)]

**So far i can see it  works ;)

**
[image]

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Like bjb568 told you, clean the cache.