# In Refinery CMS, how do I replace the favicon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon, refinerycms

I have replaced the file located at `public/favicon.ico` with my icon file. But when I load the page, I still see the default Refinery warped bumblebee icon.

I have [done the various refresh tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh) to ensure I'm not looking at a cache.

Looking at the source, the icon url is `/assets/favicon.ico`. When I load that url directly, I still see the old favicon.

I have also searched my project directory for other favicon files, but mine is the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it. I copied my favicon file into the `app/assets/images` folder.

Then I used this tag in my head partial:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag image_path('favicon.ico?v=2') %>
```