# favicon requests in firefox

Tags: html, favicon

Only in firefox I am seeing continuous favicon request even though I linked favicon in my header

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" media="all" href="${originalContextPath}${favIconPath}" />
```

Any inputs.

Comment: Please post the generated markup

Comment: If you have loaded the page before you changed the favicon you will [need to force a favicon refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)