# HTML file doesn't change after editing

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Here is the problem:

I am using `visual studio 2013`. I have a project with HTML files. I have added MasterPage to the project and one WebForm. I am loading the HTML file in the WebForm, so far so good, the file loads.

After I have edited the HTML file, I build the solution and launch my website. It loaded old version of the HTML file (the one before I edited it).

Tried to rename the HTML file, that helped, now the file loads with changes.
Renamed it back to previous name it loads again without changes.
Tried to Clean Solution, that didn't helped.

Any ideas why?
Thank you.

Comment: sometimes this happens to me 2, maybe the file is currently in use by other programs and is locked?

Comment: Have you tried pressing 'ctrl + F5' to refresh the browser after loading the page?

Comment: @MicrosoftDN Before I launch my project I close my web browser program. And tried to refresh the page as well.

Comment: @Viscocent I don't think that any other program is using the file, at least I can't find any.

Comment: add a querystring to the end of your URL, e.g., `mypage.html?v=1`

Comment: @NicholasV. your trick fixed the problem. Just was wondering what does the "?v=1" do to the file?

Comment: See my answer - specifically the answer linked, and the comments associated with said answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to the end of your URL, e.g., `mysite/mypage.html?v=1`

The logic for doing this was pulled from a very popular StackOverflow article on refreshing favicon icons, see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116701/2654498).