# Favicon not displaying though .ico exists

Tags: html, favicon

My favicon won't show even though it exists and works when visiting link directly.

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/ico/favicon.ico">
```

When I use view source on Chrome and click the above link, it takes me to the favicon.

**Tried:**

1. I have tried clearing cache but it did not help.
2. Opening in IE the favicon works.

Comment: try placing it in the root of your site

Comment: @JonasGrumann When I open the page in internet explorer it works fine.

Comment: Best practice is to place the favicon in the root directory of the website as @JonasGrumann suggested.

Comment: Try to use absolute URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to clear cache, restart my browser, then tried my site again and it works fine. Thank you all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">       
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue, I was finally able to resolve the issue by changing `favicon.ico` to something like `favicon.ico?date=20140528`. I was led that that solution by this question:
[How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Answer (score 0):

Or wait a moments and it will work correctly !
 cause server refersh