# Joomla site's favicon updated automatically

Tags: php, google-chrome, joomla, yahoo-api, invite

We have site http://kisan.co.in

We are using invite APIs of various Email and Social Network providers.

When user uses Yahoo or Gmail for invites
and comes back to our site after authentication from APIs.

Site's favicon is updated automatically.
The new favicon shown is of Yahoo or Google.

This happens only on Chrome. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

I checked source of the page. Following is the LOC which is perfect(expected favicon).

`<link href="http://kisan.co.in/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />`

Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it's a Chrome bug. Try it in other browsers, and if it only happens in Chrome I'd recommend adding the [tag:chrome] tag to your issue.

Comment: @user2428118 Yes, it happens only in Chrome. Added tag and edited post. Thanks!! Do you know any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Favicons are notorious for not updating when you want them to. Also, each browser seem to handle refreshing differently.

**How to force a favicon refresh:** [How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

- Try the above and see if it makes any difference in Chrome.

**How to force it in Chrome specifically:** https://superuser.com/questions/375321/how-to-refresh-bookmark-favicons-in-chrome

Comment: The following trick has worked for me for even the most stubborn cached favicons... Change the link in your html to: `<link href="http://kisan.co.in/images/favicon.ico?v=1" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />` By including the querystring variable `?v=1` you force a refresh. If you wanted to take this to an extreme and force a refresh on every single page load you could use a random value instead of a `1`.