# Ruby on Rails favicon not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, favicon

This `<% favicon_link_tag '/favicon.ico' %>` is in the head section of my application.html.erb file within my layouts folder.

My favicon is stored in assets, and is not rendering in the browser tab.

Any idea why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: You might still have `public/favicon.ico`, try removing it and refresh your browser.

Comment: try with `<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>`

Comment: So strange, no luck. And nothing is remaining in \public

Comment: @Zack, suggest trying http://stackoverflow.com/a/5239747

Comment: Try clearing you browser cache, or use another browser. If that works, then it is a caching problem.

Comment: did you place your favicon in just `assets/images/` or any folders inside like the `assets/images/folder` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the output Rails is sending to your browser. You'll find no mention of a favicon, as you're not actually *outputting* anything.

`favicon_link_tag` is a plain old Ruby function. It returns a value, which is a string, containing the HTML markup for a link tag to your favicon. You're taking that value, and throwing it away.

You need to **output** that value, and in ERB, you do that with `<%=`, not `<%`.

Replace your `<% favicon_link_tag ... %>` with `<%= favicon_link_tag ... %>` and you'll find that you suddenly have a `<link rel="shortcut icon" ... />` appearing in the HTML being output by your Rails app.

Comment: Outstanding, indeed a very great catch.