# Dynamic Favicon Images in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, favicon

I need to be able to return different favicon images from MVC based on context in the request. I have tried a few things but can't seem to intercept requests for `favicon.ico` and write a custom ico file to the response. I've tried a custom route handler and a custom http handler. In both cases, they never seem to get called. Can someone help shed some light on the problem?

**Custom Route Handler**

Here is the route handler code

```
public class FaviconRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var path = "/favicon.ico"; // business logic added here to set dynamic source path

        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/x-icon";
        context.RewritePath(path);

        return new DefaultHttpHandler();
    }
}
```

Here is the route configuration added in global.asax

```
routes.Add(new Route("favicon.ico", new FaviconRouteHandler()));
```

**Custom HTTP Handler**

Here is the http handler code

```
public class FaviconHttpHandler : IHttpHandler, IRouteHandler
{
    public RequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }

    public FaviconHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        this.RequestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var path = "/favicon.ico"; // business logic added here to set dynamic source path

        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "image/x-icon";
        response.WriteFile(path);
        response.End();
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Here is the handler registration added to system.webserver. Another was added to system.web in the web.config file

```
  <add name="FaviconHandler" verb="GET" path="favicon.ico" type="MyProject.FaviconHttpHandler"/>
```

For context: I am using VS 2013, MVC4

Comment: Since the favicon is cached you have to force the browser to actually download a new one check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: @RobertAguilar I am using Fiddler so I am completely skipping the cache. I still don't see the handler getting hit. I am wondering if there is a reserved behaviour related to favicon.ico