# Browser is not making any call for favicon

Tags: html, spring-mvc, favicon

I have an spring application and i want to show favicon image.
In my case browser is not making any call favicon image by itself.
I tried

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<spring:url value="/assests/login/img/favicon.ico"/>"></link>
```

I also tried setting profile attribute in head

```
<head profile="http://www.w3.org/2005/10/profile">
```

in both cases browser is not making any call for favicon

Comment: Possibly a spelling mistake in the word /assets/

Comment: yea... but in network tab i should see any call for favicon

Comment: What browser are you using? e.g. Chrome caches favicons quite strongly.

Comment: I tested in chrome and firefox, also checked restarting browsers and clearing caches

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant when I said strongly. Try the solution from  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="assests/login/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="assests/login/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: worked with <link rel="icon" href="assests/login/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assests/login/img/favicon.ico" />
```

or :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assests/login/img/favicon.ico" />
```