# Favicon not working in IE11; works in FF and Chrome

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer-11, favicon, ico

### The problem

(I have my favicon working in Firefox and Chrome already.) In Internet Explorer 11, my version, I can't seem to get the d*ng favicon to work. I have my file stored as .ico, and I have an alternate for Firefox, because you can use 64x64 .pngs in there. It shows the default icon IE has for pages.

### The info

**Windows Version - *10***
**Internet Explorer Version - *11***
**Icon file type - *.ico***

### The script

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Provide a ressouce for us to try it

Comment: How do you access your page? Via HTTP (ie. URL starts with http://) or via file system (ie. URL starts with file://)? Because some browsers won't process your favicon correctly when accessed via file system.

Comment: @philippe_b I'm still editing it, so I'm opening index.html on my PC.

Comment: Then I advice you to make it accessible via HTTP to do serious debugging. Or you can ignore this issue until to you are ready to switch to HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

Favicons do not work in Internet Explorer when the page is local file system file (`file://...`).

Answer (score -1):

I've wasted a ton of time on this.  The only solution I found that was totally foolproof is to just change the favicon programmatically once the entire application is loaded.  See

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29465098/393274