# Why do favicons get refreshed so rarily?

Tags: html, favicon

I know how to [force refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh) a favicon on a website.

But I would really like to know the reason why it is common with all browsers to refresh **favicons** in such huge time intervals. After all, images get refreshed much more often.

I'm not looking for a solution, I would just like to know the **why**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because many servers are configured to tell the browsers to cache (save) files like favicons to reduce the number of requests for files that rarely change.