# Favicon won't show in any browser

Tags: html, favicon

I've got a problem with my website; the favicon won't show no matter what I try.

My home page is

```
http://www.emilienpetit.com/Index2.html
```

and the favicon is located at

```
http://www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico
```

The current code is

```
link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico"/
```

but I tried with `rel="icon"` only and with `type="image/jpg"` `"image/x-con" "image/ico"` etc.

Can you please tell me what else I could try for it?

Regards,

Comment: Your issue is that you don't have a favicon uploaded to http://www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico. When I go to that URL, I get a web page with not much on it (possibly it's a 404 page?)

Comment: favicons are aggressively cached. Try adding a query string parameter in your HTML. As seen in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: the favicon shows on IE 11

Answer (score 6):

Your href is a little off. Currently:

```
href="www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico"
```

will attempt to hit the url:

```
http://www.emilienpetit.com/www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico
```

So you'll either have to add the http:// or use a relative link.

```
href="http://www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico"
```

or:

```
href="/favicon.ico"
```

**Edit**

I noticed that it looks like all of your links are facing the same problem. I would suggest either keeping all the links relative to your root or, if you're using server-side processing, setting up a 'base url' so that you don't have to redefine the url each time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend replacing `www.emilienpetit.com/` with just `/` because currently the webpage is saying the favicon is in `http://www.emilienpetit.com/www.emilienpetit.com/favicon.ico`.  Putting `/favicon.ico` will lead the browser to the favicon.