# Rails and Nginx: Overwritten images not reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a web server with Nginx and Passenger.

I have uploaded my rails app and got it running. Everything was great, but then I decided to change an image (overwrite it with another one). I did that, and then deployed again. I have verified that the new image was at the assets/images folder.

The problem is that I refreshed the web app, and the html was referencing the old image. It was like this, until **I restarted nginx**. Isn't any other way to reloading this? Because if i have multiple web app on the same server, I don't want to restarting them all just because I updated one web assets.

My nginx conf:

```
server {
    # Path to ruby version
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/ruby;

    listen       80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /var/www/myrailsapp/current/public;
    rails_env production;

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
       expires 1y;
       add_header Cache-Control public;

       add_header ETag "";
       break;
    }

    location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
      expires 365d;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
```

Do you know what is the problem and how can I avoid to restart nginx for reloading the new image?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/7116701/2502605

Comment: That's the browser caching the image.  This is why Rails fingerprints assets via the asset pipeline:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

You should consider enabling the assets pipeline and precompiling them when they change.

Comment: @Roko - Not a great idea.  See: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

Comment: @SeanHuber I have the assets pipeline enabled. In fact, the image is something like "my-image-fa62eadf3c561e06de9372909a1d48530a23ee9afbe514027422ff8e4f71c352.jpg". The problem is that when assets were recompiled, and the another image was created, the html didn't change so It kept referencing the old image. What could it be?

Comment: Gotchya. Is this html part of a Rails' view (layout, template, or partial) or are you talking about a static html page (likely under /public).  Unless it's static, you are going to need to restart your Rails server (passenger).  This is quicker than a full nginx restart.  Execute the command `touch <app_dir>/tmp/restart.txt`.  Reference: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/restart_app.html#restart-txt

Comment: Thanks @SeanHuber . What I had to do was restarting passenger!

Comment: Glad it worked! Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of restarting nginx, just restart passenger:

```
touch <app_dir>/tmp/restart.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

For further references, with the help of @SeanHuber what I had to do was restart just the app on passenger.

I did it running the command:

```
passenger-config restart-app
```

For more information: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/restart_app.html#restart-txt