# Django: Cannot update static file

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have two image files for favicon.ico .
Let me assume they are 'apple.ico' (image of an apple) and 'orange.ico' (image of an orange)

If i change the name of 'apple.ico' to 'favicon.ico' and put it into the static file `static/favicon.ico`.

Then, in my template file:
    `#base.html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicon.ico" %}" />`
And in the `settings.py` file: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

I can see the apple in http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/favicon.ico

And then i delete the favicon.ico file `static/favicon.ico` (image of an apple).
I change `orange.ico` to `favicon.ico` and put it into my static file.
I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/favicon.ico
I suppose i can see the image of an orange but instead the image of an apple is displayed.
The image of apple still shows up even if i delete all the static file.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh

Comment: Thanks, i solved this problem.

Comment: Shift + F5 and restart browser