# Is this the newest laravel's default favicon?

Tags: laravel-5

Today i install a new laravel application. I found that default favicon is not the same as eariler in my computer. And `favicon.ico` file is broken in `public` folder. So i want to know whether this is laravel's newest favicon?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `laravel new site` (Laravel Installer 1.3.2, Laravel 5.2), I also have a zero byte `favicon.ico` file generated under `site/public`. Your browser is likely ignoring it.

Browsers can be overly aggressive about caching favicons, so it's possible that this icon is being pulled from the cache of a previous development site or web server you might've run at the same URL.

Try updating the `favicon.ico` in the `public` folder, and then try [some of the options here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh) for forcing a favicon refresh.

It's possible that the Laravel team purposely included en empty/invalid favicon so that the browser *wouldn't* cache the icon they included, allowing you to create and add your own without having to jump through hoops to force the refresh.