# Reset favicon html

Tags: html, favicon

I'm working on a project. Using mamp on a Mac. I'm trying to reset the favicon but my browser is bound and determined to not change it.

First I switched files
Then I turned mamp off and on
Then I emptied catch and hard reset
Then then I completely removed the original directory and emptied catch...still there 
Then I restarted my computer entirely and reset catch

This is one stubborn favicon

How do I reset my favicon?

```
<head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="foo">
    <meta name="keywords" content="foo">
    <meta name="author" content="foo">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 minimum-scale=1">

    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/favicon-194x194.png" sizes="194x194">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/favicon/manifest.json">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/favicon/mstile-144x144.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicon/browserconfig.xml">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">


</head>
```

The folder the favicons are in is called "favicon" and it's at the root of my server.

Comment: Just upload a new one.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I did, I even removed the code pointing to the other one & the location of the other one. Uploaded the new one and reinserted the code...it's still there

Comment: does it happen on all the browsers?

Comment: @LelioFaieta only sticking in chrome at the moment

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh) for the answer:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try appending version numbers in the image files and see if it works? Something like

```
href="/favicon/favicon-32x32.png?v=1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you change the name of the file and in your code. Than clear your cache files from the browser and refresh. Chrome tends not to update it's cache files when you refresh the page.

Comment: I'm emptying catch and then hard reseting, while also shutting down google chrome completely and reopening. It still is displaying the same favicon

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Chrome is a bit difficult with this.