# why would the favicon from a previous project be overwriting my current projects favicon

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, favicon, create-react-app

the favicon from my last group project now shows up in any new project i create. Is there a global setting or something I don't know about. Can't for the life of me figure out how it's getting applied or how to stop it from happening. any ideas or direction would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Favicon is known for being lazily refreshed by browsers. Sure, you can [force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh). Yet I doubt this is what you need here.

I make the assumption that your new project (let's call it Project B) has nothing to do with your first project (Project A). Apparently, your browser considered that Project A favicon was suitable (from a URL point of view) for Project B. This seems to indicate that you hosted both projects at the same place. For example, you hosted Project A at `http://example.com` a few months ago, and you replaced it with Project B. So `http://example.com` is now the regular URL to access Project B.

A best practice would be to host Project B on another URL. For example, `http://project-a.example.com` and `http://project-b.example.com`. Or `http://example.com/project-a` and `http://example.com/project-b`. That will fix the favicon issue. But more important, you have a clear mapping between URLs (eg. `http://example.com/project-a`) and resources (eg. the actual Project A). That's the way the Web works and it is a good thing to follow its rules whenever possible.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I was just using them in localhost and am guessing what you said would apply to that as well. Just clearing the cache fixed everything for me. I never expected that to be an issue and couldn't figure out how it was getting from one project to the other. lol i forget about browser caches sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it as soon as i asked this question. something to do with historyApiFallback caching it. just had to clear my image cache in google and problem solved. sorry for silly question