# I made a new favicon, but whenever i enter in the code from my old website, it immediately goes back to the old one

Tags: github

I was having a problem with my favicon previously, (here is my old favicon [http://imgur.com/a/cATBc](https://imgur.com/a/cATBc)) (if you cant see it, it is a tiny blue dot in the corner of the screen)

But now, whenever I enter even a snippet of my old code, it immediately goes back to that favicon, even though I deleted all traces of it from my computer and GitHub.
My new favicon is a pug face.

Edit: ANY new website I make now has the old favicon.
Any help?

NEW EDIT: my website files are here: https://github.com/Pugplays42/htmlstuff

Comment: Is it possible that GitHub still has the old favicon cached and is therefore still using that?  Maybe you need to wait for some amount of time.

Comment: It's been a day

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/Pugplays42/htmlstuff/blob/f0034b326a01392341f6eddf2132618d4164c97e/index.html#L6, did you try to reference the icon as a file (as in https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet) instead of an embedded content?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`favicon-cheat-sheet`](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet) from [Audrey Roy Greenfeld](https://github.com/audreyr).
Especially the "[Forcing a Favicon Refresh](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet#forcing-a-favicon-refresh)" section:

- Clear the browser cache on Windows (Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R) and on Mac (Command + Shift + R).

> - Also close and reopen browser if IE.
>     If still stuck, try opening new tab. Or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)
> - Temporarily add explicit HTML markup and append a query string. Remove this when you're done:

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/favicon.ico?v=2" />
    <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="/favicon.ico?v=2">
```

> For large versioned deployments, if all site visitors need their favicon force-refreshed in an extreme situation:
>
> - Add explicit HTML markup (customize the sizes part) and put your version number in the filename.

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon-v2.ico" />
    <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32" href="/favicon-v2.ico">
```