# How do I get a favicon to show?

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm going through the tutorial on the angular-meteor.com. **What I am asking about is just for a fullstack angular-meteor web page and not for your standard static html page.** How do I get a favicon to show instead of the default page favicon? Where do I put it in the file structure? Right now it is in the same folder as the index.html(client/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force a favicon refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Comment: Please notice the [angular-meteor] tag and that I state it is already in the same place as the index.html file and not having an effect. I also coded it into the index file and still no effect. Only answer if you have experience with Meteor javascript preferably with Angular javascript.

Answer (score 0):

By default you should put it to your website's root folder with name `/favicon.ico`.

So in this case your file structure should look like this:

```
 \ - index.html
   - favicon.ico
```

or this:

```
 \ - favicon.ico
   \ html
     - mypage.html
     - favicon.ico  - it is not readed by default
```

But you can override the default icon by adding the following tag to your header element:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/path/image.png" />
```

Most of the modern browsers support ico, png, gif formats. Some of them also supports SVG format.

In Safari browser you should also define a pinned tab icon by adding the floowing lines to your html header:

```
<link rel="mask-icon" href="website_icon.svg" color="red">
```

You can read more about favicon in specs: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#rel-icon

Comment: Please look at comments above then edit or delete answers accordingly