# How to change default favicon icon in angular 2 app?

Tags: angular, favicon

- os: win32 x64
- angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
- node: 7.1.0

Repro steps.

- Remove the line

  ```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  ```

  from index.html
- ng build
- ng serve
- browse through http://localhost:4200/

It still shows the default angular favicon.
Also tried the above steps after clearing the browser cache and still the same issue.

Below browser are used to reproduced the issue:

- Chrome(Version 54.0.2840.99 m)
- IE(Version 11.0.98600.18499)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force a favicon refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Comment: Just check the generated index.html page. If it doesn't have any link to the favicon, then it's simply a browser caching issue, and you should not care

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your icon file into **/public** or **/src/assets** folder. This will make your icon visible to the browser. See [the branch on Github.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2232)

Answer (score 4):

For Angular 9

1. I created a favicon.png file in /src and dropped the image inside the file
2. In angular.json add the file to assets

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.png"
          ]
```

3. In index.html use this script

```
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
```

4. You may need to clear your cache if you're using Chrome.

   ```
    for Windows: CTRL F5 
    for Mac: CMD SHIFT R
   ```