# Github Pages website favicon not showing

Tags: html, github, github-pages, favicon

I'm hosting a website using Github Pages. I connected Cloudflare to the website because of SSL. When i finally added `favicon.ico` to my website and the following code in `<head>` to make the favicon show up, it still doesn't show up. What can i do?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

(english is not my native language)

**Edit:** Seems like other people can see the favicon, except me. But why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh?rq=1 Try any of these

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I force a favicon refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh)

Answer (score 15):

I have had the exact same problem. I was able to solve it by including a ? in the end.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?">`

I am not exactly sure why adding in `?` works but the code below does not.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico?">`

Comment: Yes it works, but why do we need that? Other files are correctly served.

Comment: I would also like to know this +1.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a question mark at the end of the path is one workaround.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="coin.png?">
```

Try also using a URL from a site that has the image, it might work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./Images/favicon.ico?">
```

if you did something like this , then go to your github.io page and hard reload.
You can use

> ctrl/cmd + shift + r

to hard reload the page . That will clear your cache .

Answer (score 2):

If you've deployed a project created using npm to Github Pages and if your build files are in a separate sub-directory, you'll have to define the path to the favicons like this (note the dot).

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./favicon-32x32.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the icon path correctly

```
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 with Firefox from Mozilla PPA just doing **Ctrl+F5** is enough.
However **F5** or a restart of Firefox is not sufficient.
I didn't know that...