# Unable to load certain images after Build in ReactJS (served with github)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, build, web-hosting

I am trying to launch my website on github. After running `npm run build`, everything loads as expected when calling `serve -s build`. However when hosted on github, [see website](https://willpowelluk.github.io/), I am unable to load the portfolio images. Strangely, I am able to access the files associated with each project.

Here is my ReactJS:

```
if(this.props.data){
            var projects = this.props.data.projects.map(function(projects){
                return <div key={projects.title} className="columns portfolio-item centreColumn">
                    <div className="item-wrap">
                        <a href={projects.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener" title={projects.title}>
                            <img alt={projects.title} src={projects.image} />
                            <div className="overlay">
                                <div className="portfolio-item-meta">
                                    <h5>{projects.title}</h5>
                                    <p>{projects.category}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="link-icon"><i className="fa fa-link"></i></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })
        }
```

and the json:

```
"portfolio": {
    "projects": [
      {
        "title": "Blah",
        "category": "blah blah",
        "image": "images/myImage.png",
        "url": "https://example.com"
      },
```

The `files` and `images` are stored in the `public folder`.

A few things I have tried:

- Different browsers
- Removing subfolders to root of `public` folder.
- Trying folder traversing like `../images/myImage.png` etc.
- Trying `src={require(projects.image).default}`.

Any suggestions much appreciated - I am impatient to get it up and running!

Comment: If you're 100% sure the images are present and named correctly, the page may not be updating. I'd check your repo settings page for any build errors and to confirm it's building the correct branch. If so, you can try pushing an empty commit, or create and switch to a new branch to force GH pages to update.

Comment: Yes I have tested to see if it serving the latest build. The images are named correctly as they work in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in path it's supposed to be .PNG capital i saw your image in github repo it's .PNG not .png

you have to change .PNG in github repo to be .png

[image]

Comment: Well solved! Ah I do hate when it's problems like these. Do you know why my favcon is not loading?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163065/github-pages-website-favicon-not-showing - solved favicon issue using question mark

Comment: No problem we all get into these troubles