# Default angular favicon not changing

Tags: angular, favicon

I have deleted the angular's default src/favicon.ico and put mine
Here is the screenshot of my visual studio code.

[image]

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Analyst</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="assets/manifest.json">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=apiLoaded" async defer></script>
  <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-71073175-1 to be your site's ID -->
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-35188202-2', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
</html>
```

But still I see the default angular favicon in browser

Comment: Did you confirm this occurs when clearing the browser cache? Flushing out any old saved files that might be hanging around.
May want to check out this post for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208933/how-do-i-force-a-favicon-refresh?rq=1